# Google Maps for other planets

Tags: coordinate-system, exogeography

I have visited, but do not remember where, Google maps for the Moon and Mars (I think). I am wondering if anyone knows what you have to do to generate the necessary GIS data (coordinate system, etc) for a completely new planet complete with aerials?

I would like to take other worlds and generate a Google Map complete with topography and draggability and more using the Google Maps API but I cannot find any information on how to do this online.

I would like to do this for both planets that are real and for fictional worlds. Think Narnia as a Google Map.

Comment: Check out this video tutorial on viewing Mars in Google Earth: http://www.google.com/earth/explore/showcase/mars.html

Comment: Narnia was flat, as was made evident in *Voyage of the Dawn Treader.*  :-)

Comment: lol @whuber true, true. I should have said that I am looking because I'm creating my own world for a sci-fi setting, RPG, and to create an immersive storyworld. I miss those books. The Dawn Treader... wow... it's been WAY too long. Thanks for the past-blast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the code at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/planetary-maptypes/planetary-maptypes.html?r=206 you will see a Google Maps solution for: Moon, Sky and Mars (elevation, visible and infrared).

To build a similar map for your planets you need to:

- choose a maxZoom and a minZoom for your map;
- build your planet raster pyramid tilesets for all your choosen zoom levels;
- choose a radius and a ...name for your planet;

Having all this you'll add a new map type for your planet:

```
//set up the map types
mapTypes['myPlanet'] = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    return getHorizontallyRepeatingTileUrl(coord, zoom, function(coord, zoom) {
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return "http://www.link_to_myPlanet_raster_pyramid_tilesets.com/" +
             + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + (bound - coord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
    });
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  isPng: false,
  maxZoom: whatever,
  minZoom: whatever,
  radius: planet_radius,
  name: 'myPlanet',
  credit: 'Image Credit: ........'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this? 
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm
Its a tutorial on how to reemplace the tile of google maps. You will be using the same gis data from earth, but maybe its ok,.

Also you can check Marble: http://marble.kde.org/features.php
Its not google maps, but its easier to generate you own map.